# What is the $n$th element of this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

$a_1=3$, $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{1+a_n}$.

How can I express the $n$th element of this sequence as a function of $n$ (not recursively)?

Comment: Did you compute the $10$ first terms ? Do you see to what value it converges ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes. It didn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$a_{n+1}=\frac1{1+a_n}$$
$$a_{n+2}=\frac1{1+\dfrac1{1+a_n}}=\frac{1+a_n}{2+a_n}$$
$$a_{n+3}=\frac1{1+\dfrac{1+a_n}{2+a_n}}=\frac{2+a_n}{3+2a_n}$$
$$a_{n+4}=\frac1{1+\dfrac{2+a_n}{3+2a_n}}=\frac{3+2a_n}{5+3a_n}$$
$$a_{n+5}=\frac1{1+\dfrac{3+2a_n}{5+3a_n}}=\frac{5+3a_n}{8+5a_n}$$
$$\cdots$$

Smells Fibonacci, doesn't it ? (Write $a_{n+k-1}$ in terms of $a_n$ and set $n=1$.)

Comment: Not _quite_ Fibonacci, though, since the initial condition doesn't give it the correct starting point.

Comment: @Arthur: I disagree. The sequence $0,1,1,2,3,5,8\cdots$ is perfectly apparent. Can't be more Fibonacci.

Comment: Yup.  My favourite proof that the limit of the ratio of the fibonacci numbers is the golden ratio.

Comment: But the sequence $a_n$ becomes $3, \frac17, \frac87, \frac{8}{15},\ldots$. That doesn't look like Fibonacci.

Comment: @Arthur Nah, the sequence for $a_n$ is defined by fibonacci numbers multiplied and added with the initial condition.

Comment: @Arthur: did I ever say that the $a_n$ were forming Fibonacci ? Anyway, there are four instances of the "golden" sequence.

Comment: You're right. The numbers that appear in your expressions certainly smell of Fibonacci.

Comment: Thank you! I am just not very familiar with the Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closed form solution should be
$$
a_n=\frac{4F_n-L_n}{4F_{n+1}-L_{n+1}}
$$
where
$$
F_n=\frac 1{\sqrt 5}(\phi^n-\phi^{-n})
$$
is the nth Fibonacci number, $L_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n+1}$ is the nth Lucas number, and $\phi=\frac{\sqrt 5+1}2$ is the Golden Ratio.

How did I get this formula? First note that almost by definition, $a_n$ is the fraction with numerator is $b_n$ and with denominator $b_{n+1}$ where $b_n$ is the sequence which is defined recursively by $b_1=3$, $b_2=1$, and $b_n=b_{n-2}+b_{n-1}$. It follows (using Linear Algebra, as explained [here](http://theanine.io/notes/closed_form_fib/) for the Fibonacci series) that $b_n=4F_n-L_n$ (you can probably just prove the equality by induction, however).

Answer (score 1):

Using matrix,

\begin{align*}
  a_{n} &= \frac{p_{n}}{q_{n}} \\
  &= \frac{0\times a_{n-1}+1}{1\times a_{n-1}+1} \\
  \frac{p_{n}}{q_{n}} &= \frac{q_{n-1}}{p_{n-1}+q_{n-1}} \\
  \begin{pmatrix} p_{n} \\ q_{n} \end{pmatrix} &=
  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix} p_{n-1} \\ q_{n-1} \end{pmatrix} \\
  &=
  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^{n-1}
  \begin{pmatrix} p_{1} \\ q_{1} \end{pmatrix} \\
  &=
  \begin{pmatrix} F_{n-2} & F_{n-1} \\ F_{n-1} & F_{n} \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
  a_{n} &= \frac{3F_{n-2}+F_{n-1}}{3F_{n-1}+F_{n}} 
\end{align*}